# cd from zsh displays wrong name of cwd (~variable)

Tags: shell, unix, zsh

I have a shell script that is run via an alias in `zsh` using `alias wd=". /path/to/wd"`. The script executes a `ruby` program and `cd`s to the output of it. It works, but after the `cd` command, the directory shows as "~result" instead of its actual name.

A simplified version of the shell script is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh

result=$(ruby engine.rb $*)
cd $result
```

It obviously has to do with the cd using a variable, "result", as that's the name it gets.

If if change to another directory and back the wrong name is still used.

Tried this is `bash` where it works correctly, so this is a `zsh` issue.

Comment: Where does the directory "show"?

Comment: No, I'm asking *you* what *you* mean.

Comment: Haha! The directory shows the wrong name in the terminal prompt. In my case it shows `simon ~result $`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a case of a static named directory being used. Because the value of `result` is a path (presumably) beginning with `/`, `zsh` is using that variable as the "name" of the path and abbreviating it when it displays the full path in your prompt. See `man zshexpn` under "Static named directories" for details.

Comment: That man page is huge! Do you know if the conclusion that I should accept it or is there a chance of a workaround?

Comment: You might be able to remove `result` from the named directory hash table with `hash -d result`.

Comment: Awesome! The solution was to remove with `unhash -d result`

Answer (score 3):

This is caused by the `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` option (which is not enabled by default):

```
         AUTO_NAME_DIRS

         Any parameter that is set to the absolute name of a directory
         immediately becomes a name for that directory, that will be used
         by the `%~' and related prompt sequences, and will be available
         when completion is performed on a word starting with `~'.
         (Otherwise, the parameter must be used in the form `~param' first.)
```

In other words, with `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` enabled whenever you do something like
`project=/path/to/my/project`, `~project` becomes an abbreviation for `/path/to/my/project`.
This lets you do things like `cd ~project` or `ls -lh ~project` as a shortcut for that directory.

If you just don't like the directory being displayed as `~project` in your prompt, you can
replace `%~` with `%d` in your prompt to always display the full path.

If you don't want this behavior at all, do `unsetopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS` in your config.

If you want to keep the option on, but disable it inside your script so it doesn't make `result` a named dir, do `emulate -LR zsh` at the top of your script. This temporarily resets all options to their defaults while the script runs. It's best practice to always use `emulate -LR zsh` in scripts to prevent weird things like this from happening. This is better than doing `unhash -d result` to fix it after the fact.

Comment: perfect, I used `%d` for the prompt. `unsetopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS` did not really work.